# Custom UITableViewCell not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell

I want to make a custom UITableViewCell that can have many columns. One will be a UILabel and one will be a UIButton. I want to start this off by saying I only create my IBOutlets by holding the control key and dragging the UI items to my code. So this means all of my IBOutlets are connected properly. My problem is that the UILabel and the UIButton are not visible in any of my cells. The cells are there, but nothing else.

[image]

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
}
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    var items: [Strings] = ["one", "two", "three"]
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.register(CustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell:CustomTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")! as! CustomTableViewCell

        cell.label?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

I have the UITableView's data source and delegate set to the ViewController, I have the cell reuse id set up properly and both the UILabel and UIButton have constraints set up. I feel like I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **must not** register the cell – when using prototype cells – but you **must** reload the table view.

Replace

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.register(CustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}
```

with

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was bothering the heck out of me. I am going to look up the reloadData method to get a better idea of what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Those are missing:

```
self.tableView.delegate = self
self.tableview.datasource = self
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It does not, because I already said that I did this in the inspector. "I have the UITableView's data source and delegate set to the ViewController". Please read everything.

Comment: I added this to my viewDidLoad just to make sure that it was not this, it did nothing.

Comment: put a debugger on : cell.label?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]  Is it passing stopping on this debugger?

Comment: It creates the cell, but nothing inside of it. I did view debugging. The content view was created but not the label or button in the content view.

Comment: can you set the cell.backgroundColor = .red and check if it is being red?

Comment: perfect, now give th label a static text --> label.text = "Hello" will it show?

Comment: try this, if it worked then the problem is in your label.         let label2 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
label2.textAlignment = .center
label2.text = "I'am a test label"
cell.addSubview(label2)

Comment: creating the label programmatically worked. why would this be an issue? do you have any thoughts?

Comment: I think the label in your storyboard in not well configured. My personal opinion (just a personal preference) is to code it pragmatically. However please show me your storyboard configuration so that I can help you.

Comment: If you feel this answer helped you kindly up vote or mark as correct if it is :)